# In Excel, I would like to count the ingredients which are in stock for certain recipes

Tags: excel

I have this table made in Excel in which the rows represent a (ceramics) recipe. Each column represents an ingredient. My first row is in use to mark (with an "X") an ingredient which I have in my stock. In column BM I count the number of ingredients needed per recipe.

Now I would like (per recipe) to count the ingredients I own, so I know which recipes are able to be mixed or are nearly able to be mixed by me.
[image]

For example:
The recipe "amberceladon" needs 7 ingredients (BM3). In the columns showing on the screenprint-image it's clear that I have "siliciumoxide" (AV1) in stock (the "X" in AV2). I would like to have expressed in BN3 the number "1". That way I know the "amberceladon" isn't to be mixed at this time, 'cause of lack of ingredients.

Just in case you wonder: the image doesn't show all columns, that's why the numbers in BM don't match what you see...

Comment: If you represent “in stock” with 1 and out of stock with 0, then you could use sumproduct().

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I understand correct, you are saying to change the "X" in a number 1 and all other ingredients should be a number 0. What would be the formula to use 'SUMPRODUCT', so I can count the number of ingredients per recipe I already have in stock?

Comment: I figured it out. The formula I used, I posted below in a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the little hint of using SUMPRODUCT I got ahead and figured it out at the end.
This one is based on the complete table. In row 2 I changed the "X"'s into number 1, and the empty cells got a zero (0). So the numbers 1 represent an ingredient I already have in stock, the numbers 0 represent an ingredient I don't own.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(Table4[@[alberta-slib]:[zircopax]]));$E$2:$BL$2)
```

This did the trick for me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to count the total number of X per row.

Solution 1: you can just turn them into 1 and then use a SUM function

Solution 2: if you do not want to change the X, then make a table on the right with the following functions =IF(J36="X", 1, 0), it will transform an X into a 1, and you can count each row

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have in column BM the amount of ingredients needed per recipe. What I would like to know is how many of these ingredients I have in stock. This way I'm able to see which recipes can already be made or can almost be made.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by counting the cells with numbers. You can also use `COUNTA`

```
=COUNT(B2:M2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I already have in column BM. I would like to have a formula in BN which tells me how many of the required ingredients per recipe I already have in stock. For every recipe (per row) I have the amount of every ingredient needed mentioned in percentages. But now I would like to know how many of these necessary ingredients I already have and don't need to buy anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by what you meant by your question but this is an excel sheet I made to track inventory for a local bakery.
[image]

So for rows 4-15, cols B-E I've written how many ingredients I require for each recipe. The recipe name is written in 2B,2C,2E. The row beneath it displays how many orders there are of that item.
So for example if you want to find out how much sugar you require. You can do so by multiplying the number of cakes ordered and how much sugar you need for each cake and do that for each recipe and sum it.
So for example for sugar you would have a formula like:
`=$B$3*B5+$C$3*C5+$D$3*D5+$E$3*E5`
and you would do this for all rows 4 to 14 and display them in column F. Column G stores the number of ingredients you already have. The H column shows how much of the ingredient you need to make/buy. So you subtract column G from F and store the result in H. So for example for Sugar you would do
`=$F$5-$G$5`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. This isn't exactly what I meant, though this is a nice format.
I have the total amount of ingredients needed per recipe in column BM. Per row is a recipe which indicates how much per ingredient is needed to mix this recipe. Now I would like to know how many of the necessary ingredients I already have in stock. That way I can easily check which recipes I can already mix and which ones I need to buy ingredients for.

Comment: @Ekfa so sumproduct(B3:E3,B5:E5) is equivalent to the formula shown and is a lot less typing. You can work out where to put the dollar signs as needed. Excel help has examples if you want to read up.

Comment: I figured it out eventually. It was all trigured by getting to start the SUMPRODUCT. But my question wasn't as easy as multiplying the percentage of an ingredient by the "amount" I had in stock.